# Bash: How to save processed value to a new variable

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, sh

i've got a string with JSON text that i want to parse

```
heat@heat-G780 ~ $ data='{"foo": 42, "bar": "less interesting data"}'
heat@heat-G780 ~ $ echo $data|jq '.foo'
42
```

but  then i can't assign this value to a variable

```
heat@heat-G780 ~ $ foo=$data|jq '.foo'
heat@heat-G780 ~ $ echo $foo
(here's nothing, trust me)
```

so, how can i assign it to a new variable?

Comment: `foo=$(echo $data | jq '.foo')`

Comment: @Phylogenesis oh, many thanks to you!

Comment: @Phylogenesis don't forget quotes around `"$data"`.